# Sauce Labs OnDemand: multiCapabilities build information is not accepted

Tags: node.js, protractor, saucelabs

We are running mocha nodejs tests with protractor on Sauce Labs and the attribute 'build' is being ignored. This is my protractor.conf.js

```
    multiCapabilities: [
    {
        name: 'chrome-tests-windows',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        version: '52',
        platform: 'Windows 7',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 25,
        build: 'solisko-1',
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
    }]
```

When I look at the metadata in Sauce Labs Dashboard I see this:

```
Build null
Tags ["tag1","tag2"]
Browser googlechrome
Browser version 52.0.2743.82
OS Windows 2008
```

Any idea why the build name is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, for the build to be populated on Sauce platform. You need to send the below property in Protractor config file. [Check here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L138)

> /**    * Use sauceBuild if you want to group test capabilities by a
>   build ID    */

```
  sauceBuild?: string;
```

I dont see a `build` option in capabilities object as per the [documentation here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)

Answer (score 0):

From different source I found out that this is the correct attribute:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        Build: 'some-build-name',
        BuildName: 'some-build-name',
        name: 'chrome-tests-mac',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        version: '52',
        platform: 'OS X 10.12',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 25
    }
]
```